# How to create a plot of vectors emanating from the x axis?

Tags: plotting, graphics, visualization, labeling

I am trying to make a plot that looks something like the image seen below:

[image: Text]
So far I have the following code:

```
ListPointPlot3D[
Table[{i, Cos[i], Sin[i]}, {i, -4 \[Pi], 4 \[Pi], 0.2}], 
AxesStyle -> Thick, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}, Filling -> Axis, 
AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}, Boxed -> False]
```

which yields the output:
[image: Text]

My problem is that the 'stalks'/'stems' of the points are all originating from the projection of the points onto the xy plane. Is there a way for me to get the stems to originate from the x axis alone so that it mimics the first photo attached?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `Graphics3D[{Red, Arrowheads -> 1/100,
  Arrow /@ 
   Table[{{i, 0, 0}, {i, Cos[i], Sin[i]}}, {i, -4 \[Pi], 
     4 \[Pi], \[Pi]/12}]}, Axes -> True, AxesStyle -> Thick,
 AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0},
 PlotRange -> {{-4 \[Pi], 4 \[Pi]}, {-2, 2}, {-2, 2}},
 ViewPoint -> {2 \[Pi], -1, 1}, Boxed -> False
 ]`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`Graphics3D`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Graphics3D.html)

```
Graphics3D[{Green, Tube[{{0, 0, 0}, {2 Pi, 0, 0}}, .04], 
  Table[{Sphere[{i, Cos[i], Sin[ i]}, .05], 
    Tube[{{i, 0, 0}, {i, Cos[ i], Sin[ i]}}, .04]}, 
   {i, 0, 2 Pi, 2 Pi/30}]},
  ImageSize -> Large, Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

or

```
Graphics3D[{Green, Tube[{{0, 0, 0}, {2 Pi, 0, 0}}, .04], 
  {Sphere[{#, Cos[ #], Sin[ #]}, .05], 
   Tube[{{#, 0, 0}, {#, Cos[ #], Sin[ #]}}, .04]} & /@ 
   Subdivide[0, 2 Pi, 30]}, 
 ImageSize -> Large, Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can use [`ParametricPlot3D`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricPlot3D.html)

```
Show[ParametricPlot3D[{t, v Cos[t], v Sin[t]}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}, {v, 0, 1}, 
  MeshFunctions -> {#4 &}, Mesh -> 30, 
  MeshStyle -> {Green, Tube[.05]}, 
  PlotStyle -> None, Boxed -> False, Axes -> False], 
 ParametricPlot3D[{t, 0, 0}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotStyle -> {Green, Tube[.05]}]]
```

[image]

**Update:** *"make the ends of the tubes arrow heads? So that they resemble vectors emanating from the x axis."*

```
Show[Normal[ParametricPlot3D[{t, v Cos[t], v Sin[t]}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}, {v, 0, 1}, 
    MeshFunctions -> {#4 &}, Mesh -> 30, MeshStyle -> Green, 
    PlotStyle -> None, Boxed -> False, Axes -> False]] /. 
  Line[x_] :> {Arrowheads[.05], Arrow[Tube[SortBy[x, Abs@ #[[2]] &], .05]]}, 
 ParametricPlot3D[{t, 0, 0}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Green, Tube[.05]}], ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

Comment: These all work perfectly, thanks so much! Just out of interest, do you know of any way to use the parametricPlot3D method you've done and make the ends of the tubes arrow heads? So that they resemble vectors emanating from the x axis.

Comment: @Salah, please see the update.